# How to detect class of UITableView inside of UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm using [PageMenu](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiylYnT3-XMAhVFwxQKHTCiBA0QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FHighBay%2FPageMenu&usg=AFQjCNEE3pDiq5uhf4IvEKC1TtoG_m5zyw&bvm=bv.122448493,d.bGg) for viewcontrollers pagination. I have one main viewcontroller and later I've added 3 UITableViewControllers into it. Now when I go to some ViewController from my MainControllers second tab, for example, and return back, it see it like the first tab, not the second.

Now I want to detect UITableView class inside of my main ViewController. How can I do it?

I've tried:

```
for vc in navigationController!.viewControllers {
        if vc is UITableViewController {
            print("POPO \(vc)")
        }
    }
```

but this code does not print anything. What I do wrong?

Comment: isKindOfClass(UITableViewController) will help

Comment: This means none of your navigation controller's view controllers are UITableViewControllers. Without more context about the structure of your app, it is difficult to help.

Comment: @Jeff no, I have! Can you please look at those repo? You'll understand the concept

Comment: @PKT it does not help me too

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if vc.isKindOfClass(UITableViewController) {
    print("POPO \(vc)")
}
```

Or

```
if let viewController = vc as? UITableViewController  {
    print("POPO \(vc)")
}
```

Comment: but it does not print anything in this case too

Comment: try `vc.isKindOfClass(UIViewController)` and see if it prints them all

Comment: Basically I don't think your ViewControllers are on the navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

```
for vc in navigationController!.viewControllers {
    if vc is UITableViewController {
        print("POPO \(vc)")
    }
}
```

This will print the statement only if the `TableViewController` is still in the `UINavigationController` stack. If you have visited the `TableViewController` and returned back through a `pop` then the same is removed from the navigation stack and no longer the above code fragment print anything. Make sure the TableViewController is in the stack to get the result in this method.